reading excel file not working on web-server using ClosedXML
I have an application where I open an excel file and populate a listbox with the headers.  I am using ClosedXML and have the ClosedXML NetGet Package installed and just tried the ClosedXML.Signed NetGet Package.  This application works as it should on my local computer in Visual Studio; however, nothing works on my server and no errors are thrown.
The webserver does not have excel installed.  I was under the impression that ClosedXML was able to work without excel installed.  Am I incorrect in this assumption?
My Code is below.
Thanks for all your help,
James
Using workbook = New XLWorkbook(fn)
    Dim worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1)
    Dim firstRow = worksheet.FirstRowUsed()
    Dim firstPossibleAddress =
        worksheet.Row(firstRow.RowNumber()).FirstCellUsed().Address
    Dim lastPossibleAddress = worksheet.LastCellUsed().Address

    Dim b As Integer = 0
    For Each cell In firstRow.Cells(firstPossibleAddress.ColumnNumber,
                                     lastPossibleAddress.ColumnNumber)
        Dim a As New ListItem
        a.Value = b
        a.Text = cell.Value.ToString()
        listExcell.Items.Add(a)
        b += 1
    Next
End Using


It's unclear what technology you're using. You mention_webserver_, and listbox,, however, you need to add a lot more information. One should be able to use the information that you've provided and re-create the issue that you're facing. Using only the information provided in this post, re-create the project and issue. I think that you'll have great difficulty in doing so.
